# Deploy Windows Form Entity Framework 6 App

Tags: winforms, deployment, entity-framework-6

I have been working on a project to create a Windows Form Application, using .NET 4.5, C#, and Entity Framework 6, in Visual Studio 2012. I was hoping to build a single EXE file to run the whole program, but I need the references to both DLLs for EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServer.

I know that I could create an installation project and package the DLLs with the EXE, but for the company I work for that does not appear to be an option. I will more than likely have to find a way to install the DLLs separately so that they will be available when the EXE is sent to the users that need access to it.

Does anybody have any advise or experience on how you deployed your applications that required the use of the DLLs for EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServer?

Comment: you mentioned 'deployment'... Then you said you're sending the .exe to the users. Is that the only method of deployment you have available? Are you unable to just use ClickOnce?

Comment: Have you tried just copying the \bin\release folder?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in responding. Unfortunately ClickOnce is not an option due to "business requirements". Is there anyway to put the two DLLs into the GAC and reference them that way?